# How can we create the jQuery fancybox elastic animation using css3 transitions

Tags: css

The elastic effect can be easily done by changing the width and height property. But how can we maintain the element within the view port?

And yeah, fancy box is placing a whole new element in the popup. But I want my original element to scale to a different size within the view port.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the following techniques to achieve this effect:

- [Fit-and-shrink](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fast.html)
- [Box Holder](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplayBox.html)